# Error installing Django

Tags: permissions, python, django

I have try to run this command and get a error

```
easy_install Django

(django-mike)zapbuild@jaskaran:~/Documents/python/django-mike$ easy_install Django
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/zapbuild/Documents/python/django-mike/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-7107.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /home/zapbuild/Documents/python/django-mike/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l  /home/zapbuild/Documents/python/django-mike/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`?

Comment: Also, have you considered using `python-pip`, `python3-pip`, or `apt-get` to do the installation?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your question is "How can I install django?", I might suggest that you do so using `pip` (python's package manager).  There are other options, but this method has been the most pleasant in my experience.

For python3, you can install pip with

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Change `python3-pip` to `python-pip` in the command above if you are using python2.

Next, you should upgrade pip (using pip to do so)

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

**Note**: the first `pip` in the above command might need to instead be `pip-3.2` or some other variant for you.  To find out what `pip` variant you need, type `pip` and then look at the tab completion suggestions.  It will be something like `pip`, `pip3`, or `pip-3.2` (or other version numbers).

You should now be all set to install django using pip:

```
sudo pip install django
```

If your question was instead "How can I install django using `easy_install`?" then I apologize for the unhelpful response.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason for specifically requiring a different version, then install Django from the repos:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-django
```

Comment: yes, `python3-django` is also available through apt-get

Comment: in python dev you always pin down your django version to a specific version, so easy_install (or better pip) is to be preferred over the repos